# Best method for reading row and col of txt file

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector, ifstream

Sorry, im a C++ noob! I have looked around for a solution but cant seem to find one that best suits my need. I am tring to read the width(max amount of char in line) and height (max amount of lines per file) of a txt file. Planning on using varaibles to help make dynamic sized txt files/levels.

I have had fixed width and height working previous to this!

TXT FILE: Simple output of chars for room layout (space=floor, #=wall, X=door):

```
########
#      #
#      X
#      #
########
```

PROBLEM: Thought this to be a simple problem, but it only reads 2 of each variable(hNum,wNum)before breaking loop and program cant continue.

-What am i doing wrong?

-Should i be using seekg or different loop somehow?

-Do i need to alter my vector to 2D vector?

-Which is the best method for achieving this?

## Room.cpp

```
//LOAD CURRENT ROOM FROM FILE

ss << RoomNo;
string str = ss.str();

    string fname = ("Room");
fname.append(str);
fname.append(".txt");
infile.open(fname);

infile.clear();
infile.seekg(0);

if(infile.is_open())
{
    // Sets width and height depndant on txt file size

    string line;

   //NOT WORKING!

    while( !infile.eof())
    {
        hNum++;
        getline ( infile, line);
        wNum += line.length();
        break;
    }
    height=hNum;
    width=wNum;

    //END

    // Loop to end of file- to get you all the lines from txt file.
    while(!infile.eof())        
    {
        int i;
        for(int row = 0; row < width; row++)
        {
            infile.getline(RoomFile, 256);
            i = 0;
            for(int col = 0; col < height; col++)
            {
                data.push_back(RoomFile[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
}
else
{
    cout << "ERROR: infile not open" << endl; 
}
infile.close();
```

## UPDATE

This is what i got, tryin to do what Sky suggested...but cudnt work it all out. Then steped thro and thought the loop wasnt active so altered the argument. Now getting runtime error!

PROBLEM: Expression: vector subscript out of range!

Suggestions anyone?

```
            string line;

    while(getline(infile,line))
    {
        getline(infile, line);
        tempVector.push_back(line);
    }
    width=line.length();
    height=tempVector.size();
```

Comment: Think my eof loop is broken, mite need alternative. eof reached early and never loops so width and height=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way that can work would be to create a vector of strings and read the entire file, with each line a string in the vector.

Rough example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

/* ... */

vector<string> content;
string buffer;
while(!infile.eof())
{
  getline(infile, &string, '/n');
  content.push_back(string);
}

width = findMaxLengthOfStrings(content);
height = content.size();
```

You are reading each line of the file as a separate string. The strings are pushed onto the vector. You can then easily find which string in the vector is longest, by iterating through the vector, using `size()`. The length in lines of the file is obtained with `size()` on the vector itself.

Also, posting just the relevant parts of the code, the I/O function, would have helped. Just saying ;) A small screen size and such.

Comment: tried it but dont think i fully understand! getline: no instance of overloaded function when adding'/n'! soz im shod at this ill look around for this elsewere, unless you care to explain the getline and width futher?

Comment: while(getline()) is incorrect. It should be while(!infile.eof()) or something similar. You're doing getline twice and reaching end of file twice as early. Also, just doing line.length() makes you get the width of the last line. You need to write a comparison function for that.